# kafka stream windowedBy not producing results when expected

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm doing this simple windowed aggregation in kafka streams:

```
...
.groupByKey(/* Serde stuff */)
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(
        Duration.ofSeconds(5)
).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(0)).until(5000))
.aggregate(
  (key, val, agg) -> {
    // aggregation here
  }, 
  Materialized.with(/* Serde stuff */)
)
.toStream()
.to("output")
```

And I would expect that every 5 seconds, it would produce to the output topic a single result, but when running it, it takes around 17 seconds.

So after referring to [this guide](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/window-final-result/kstreams.html), I changed `CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG` to `0` and made the code into this (Only adding the `suppress` step:

```
...
.groupByKey(/* Serde stuff */)
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(
        Duration.ofSeconds(5)
    ).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(0)).until(5000))
.aggregate(
      (key, val, agg) -> {
    // aggregation here
  }, 
  Materialized.with(/* Serde stuff */)
)
.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
.toStream()
.to("output")
```

When running the second attempt, it outputs nothing, when debugging, I see the messages being processed through the stream with no exceptions in the logs, but nothing comes out.

Did I miss anything? shouldn't this code produce results every 5 seconds?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the case you are trying to solve?

Comment: Can you add some of the missing details on  Materialized.with(/* Serde stuff */)

Comment: @HaimRaman, I have events that I need to group by key (which is the type of event) 
and aggregate them into one single record that contains all event types that are consumed during the 5 second window

Comment: @HaimRaman, as for the details, in `Materialized.with`, it's not related at all, but in case you need its: `Materialized.with(Serdes.String(),SerdeFactory.JsonSerde(QueueChangedEvent.class))` where the factory is creates custom Serde based on Json, and there's no problem in serialization/deserialization, because the flow works fine except for the timing.

Comment: I don't want to answer as I am new to Kafka stream and not sure I am right here . Following this post https://www.nerd.vision/post/suppress-surprise-kafka-streams-and-the-suppress-operator The suppress operator is based on event-time and as long as no new records arrive the stream is basically frozen.

Comment: @HaimRaman, you are right, the code is ok, but tests are not, [this post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/) explains how to test them too (which is linked through the post you provided), basically I had to do this in my tests to make them work: (1) produce test data (2) produce a dummy event with future timestamp to release the window result (3) assert. And each test needs to be isolated (i.e bring Kafka broker and the stream up before and turn off after each individual test. Thanks, you can answer the question with these details and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this post https://www.nerd.vision/post/suppress-surprise-kafka-streams-and-the-suppress-operator

The suppress operator is based on event-time and as long as no new records arrive the stream is basically frozen.

This [post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/) explains how to test this.

For the tests to work you need:

1. produce test data
2. produce a dummy event with future timestamp to
   release the window result  assert.

Note that each test needs to be isolated
(e.g bring Kafka broker and the stream up before and turn off after each individual test or close the test driver).